# Black Screen appearing when inflate the layout in Activity?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I have a problem  when before inflate the layout (i.e in that layout have loading live cameras )the black screen will appearing.The problem is that the layout needs to load live cameras.

How can I manage this thing?

This is the my code:

mydialog.dismiss();

```
        try {
            views.clear();
            JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(result);
            Log.e("iserror is", "<><>" + jsonobject.getString("IsError"));
            JSONArray jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("Cameras");
            Log.e("array lenght is", "<><>" + jsonarray.length());
            cameraslist.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                Cameras cameras = new Cameras();
                cameras = gson.fromJson(jsonarray.getJSONObject(i)
                        .toString(), Cameras.class);
                cameraslist.add(cameras);
            }
            if (jsonarray.length() == 0) {
                rel_mainlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ll_homecameras.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else{
                rel_mainlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ll_homecameras.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                inflateDynamicViewToLinearLayout(ll_homecameras,
                        cameraslist, position_onresume);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //mydialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Can you tell me any solution? Or advice?